# Installation of module node-red-node-arduino failed:

Tags: arduino, node-red

I am trying to install the node-red node-arduino through the Manage Palette install feature as outlined in the node-red website instructions. Node-red is installed on my Windows 10 PC and I have an Arduino connected through a USB COM port. The Arduino has Standard Firmata loaded to the board. When I try to install the arduino-node I get a lengthy error message, that seems to be unsuccessfully searching for Python, although nothing in the requirements for the node-arduino mentions Python. Here is the error message:

```
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.16.1 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.ex...
```

Note: above is the error message, not code, but had to mark it as such to get post accepted

I am new to Node-Red, so any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a requirement for any nodejs package that has to build a native component. In this case it will need to build the `node-serial` module in order to access the COM port. You will need to install a supported version of Python in order to get this to work.

Comment: I was finally able to install node-arduino. Thanks so much for your assistance!!

Comment: @Hawkeyeknight https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Facing the same issue. Can you please elaborate the answer please

Comment: @spd What more do you need? You need to have python installed on the machine in order to install the required pre-requist node, node-serial. The error message in the original question is pretty clear.